# youarehere class mysteriously gone from flags tab

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, design

The flags tabs available on the moderator tools dashboard (http://example.com/admin/dashboard)  no longer has the `youarehere` class assigned to it when that tab is active. Other tabs behave fine.

#### History tab

[image]

#### Flags tab

[image]

Comment: Also happening on Scifi and TGO.

Comment: `.youarenowhere`

Comment: @animuson Does that say "you are now here" or "you are no where"..? xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: I forgot to add a condition to enable it on that page.

Long version: that tab works differently from the other because it's shared with the moderator tools (under `tools`). It needed special casing to work correctly under `/admin`.

It will be pushed out in the next build.